# Concatenating an int to a string in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, string-concatenation

How do I concatenate the `int length` to the string I'm trying to slap into that array so it is "**C10**" given length == 10, of course. I see `@"%d", intVarName` way of doing it used else where. In Java I would of done `"C" + length;`. I am using the `replaceObjectAtIndex` method to replace the empty string, "", that I have previously populated the `MSMutableArray` "board" with. I am getting an error though when I add the `@"C%d", length` part at the end of that method *(**second to last line, above `i++`**)*.

As part of my homework I have to randomly place "Chutes" (represented by a string of format, "C'length_of_chute'", in this first assignment they will always be of length 10 so it will simply be "C10") onto a game board represented by an array.

```
   -(void)makeChutes: (int) length {// ??Change input to Negative number, Nvm.
    //??Make argument number of Chutes ??randomly?? across the board.
    for(int i = 0; i < length;){
        int random = arc4random_uniform(101);
        if ([[board objectAtIndex:random] isEqual:@""]) {
            //[board insertObject:@"C%d",length atIndex:random];
            [board replaceObjectAtIndex:random withObject:@"C%d",length];
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Please ignore the extra and junk code in there, I left it in for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C the `stringWithFormat` method is used for formatting strings:

```
NSString *formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"C%d", length];
[someArray insertObject:formattedString];
```

It's often easier to create your formatted string on a line of its own in Objective-C, since as you can see the call can be fairly verbose!

Comment: Thanks! I thought that having to format the string on it's own line might be the case.

Comment: You don't have to (you can nest the calls) - I would say doing so makes the code slightly less readable though. That's just my opinion, mind.